# Ad anchor at the end of url

Tags: javascript, replace, anchor

I have to add a few line to the js below.
What I want to do is add a #id at the end of the URL "%%cta%%" . 
Can someone help me? thanks a lot!

```
thisthing.replaceData = function (thisTemplate, htmlList, htmlOverlayer, dataJs, indexLi) {
    //thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%img%%', '/B2C/ResourcesWebRevise/booking/thisthing/custom/' + dataJs + '.jpg');
    thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%title%%', thisthingData.title);
    thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%desc%%', thisthingData.desc);
    thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%cta%%', thisthingData.cta); // bridge cta
    thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%list%%', htmlList);
    thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%overlayer%%', htmlOverlayer);
    thisthing.print(thisTemplate, dataJs, indexLi);
}
```

Comment: So you want url like this `http://foo.bar/Data/CTA#id/MoreData` or `http://foo.bar/Data/CTA/MoreData#id`

Comment: Something like this /B2C/ResourcesWebRevise/booking/thisthing/custom/page.aspx#id

Comment: Then check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that's what you need. Just add to end of string using `+=`.

```
thisthing.replaceData = function(thisTemplate, htmlList, htmlOverlayer, dataJs, indexLi) {
  //thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%img%%', '/B2C/ResourcesWebRevise/booking/thisthing/custom/' + dataJs + '.jpg');
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%title%%', thisthingData.title);
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%desc%%', thisthingData.desc);
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%cta%%', thisthingData.cta); // bridge cta
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%list%%', htmlList);
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%overlayer%%', htmlOverlayer);
  thisTemplate += "#id"; // Pretty simple
  thisthing.print(thisTemplate, dataJs, indexLi);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your help! in this way i add + #id to all %%name%% correct? What i have to do is to add the id only to %%cta%% . Sorry maybe I explained badly

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking about with code you provided. What do you mean "only to %%cta%%"? Can you tell me what this function print? An output example.

Comment: The function print a link here : <a href="%%cta%%" class="cta" ></a> i have to add an anchor link

Comment: i try to solve by do this : `
  thisTemplate = thisTemplate.replace('%%cta%%', thisthingData.cta + '#id'); // bridge cta